# Use of Garbage Collector in Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: c#

I was reading about garbage collector. I wanted to knwo what is the use of Garbage Collector in Object Oriented programming? We can also delete the object manually instead of Garbage Collector.
And then we have the Generation of Garbage Collector which has ceratin levels N,N+1,N+2. Are they really so imporatnt?

Comment: ...?  GC and OOP are orthogonal concepts.  You can have either without the other.

Comment: What did you read about garbage collection? Did you at least read carefully http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29 ? Consider also reading the http://gchandbook.org/

Comment: considering you have C# tagged, the garbage collection is done for you. You have the option to use something known as the "finalizer" with this syntax: "~" before the call. Removal of an object reference is handled after run time and before execution has stopped, so unless you're somehow writing unsafe code, you don't have to worry about handling exposed memory.

Comment: @Ben: GC is something entirely different than that.  It's what keeps the memory from filling up, basically.  It *calls* the finalizer, as part of its job.  But the finalizer is not the GC.

Comment: @user1739035: Is your question focusing on C# specifically? Or on the concept of GC? This is important in order to answer properly on what you are after.

Comment: @cHao yeah I didn't mean to express it like that, thank you :)

Comment: Sorry everyone if my question has troubled you. I couldnt understand about the concept of Garbage Collector as I thought that developers could also manage the memory although its troublesome so I was expecting a logical answer. But here everyone has downvoted me and I cant ask any further questions now :(

Answer (score 6):

Garbage Collection has nothing to do with Object Oriented Programming.

C# is a Managed Language. That means that the developer doesn't need to worry (at least, shouldn't have to worry) about memory management. That is why the Garbage Collector is so important.

Answer (score 3):

> We can also delete the object manually instead of Garbage Collector

Yes, we can - but it might get us into serious troubles of:

1. [Memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)
2. [Dangling Pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)

Usage of GC's is usually decreasing the development time significantly, but when using it - we suffer some performance - loss, especially when it comes to [latency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latency_%28engineering%29).

Comment: I would make a distinction between deleting an object and reclaiming its memory for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're writing `unsafe` code, you don't free memory in C#.

Answer (score 0):

The Garbage Collector and Object Oriented Programming are completely separate concepts. You might be confusing them since many OOP languages implement some form of a Garbage Collector.

Garbage collection is the process of cleaning up unused resources - meaning objects that have gone out of scope, etc. It allows the programmer to not worry (for the most part) about cleaning up after himself.

C# is a managed language - meaning it implements a Garbage Collector, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

The two concepts are completely unrelated.

You can have one and not the other. You may be able to *delete* an object in a garbage collected language, but you don't get to *reclaim the memory*. That is the responsibility of the garbage collector in all languages I've worked with

To prove that they are completely different concepts, here's a short list of languages with/without oop/gc:

**Both Garbage Collector and Object Oriented:**

- C#
- Java
- Countless others

**Object Oriented, but not Garbage Collected:**

- C++

**Garbage Collected but not Object Oriented:**

- JavaScript*

**Neither Garbage Collected, nor Object Oriented:**

- C

---

*While JavaScript has *objects*, is not object oriented in the same way as C++ & Java. I would call it a prototype based language rather than an object oriented language.

Comment: Did you really include Smalltalk in the "not object oriented" category?  It's one of maybe two languages that practically *invented* OO.

Comment: @cHao, my reason for including it was based on the influence that it had on JavaScript, but I can't say that I know enough about it to say one way or the other. I would *guess* that it is also prototype based, which I consider different form object oriented, but its a wild *** guess. I'll just say JavaScript and leave it at that.

Comment: @cHao, and a brief reading of it on Wikipedia confirms that I was wrong. Javascript seems to have been based on Self, which was based on Smalltalk, but Self seems to have introduced the concept of a prototype. Oh well.

Comment: "Class-based" != "object-oriented".  :)  You can have objects without classes.  I'd actually argue JS is just as OO as any other language, considering prototypes do just as well as classes to enable the concepts behind OOP.  But really, i'd rather not get too into a discussion about that.  :)

Comment: @cHao, I generally use OOP to refer to a class based paradigm. Let those with far too much time on their hands decide what the exact terminology is. It is extremely unlikely that the op knows the difference in the first place.